# Does Xcode >= 9.1 no longer generate "This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key xxx" messages for busted outlets?

Tags: ios, xcode9.1

If you have a storyboard/XIB with an IBOutlet connected to the corresponding IBOutlet property in your code and then you delete the outlet in code, you used to crash with a rather cryptic error message to the effect that "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key `<outlet_name>`"

This isn't my first Xcode rodeo, so I'm used to that message. I see it and thing "oh crap, I've either got a broken outlet link or a user-defined runtime attribute that points to an invalid key name" and go fix it.

However, my company just moved to Xcode 9.1 (I know, we should be on 9.2, never mind 9.1, but we have a big team and a huge mixed Swift/Objective-C codebase, and migrating our toolchain is fraught with complexity.) I just had a merge error where a now-defunct outlet was left in a Storyboard.

When I ran the app and exercised the code-path that should display this scene in my storyboard, I got a crash in main.m, with nothing in the stack trace, and no clues in the console. Just SPLAT.

I wasted 2 hours tracking this puppy down.

The error message used to be cryptic as h**l, but at least it gave you a clue. Now it seems you just crash with no explanation.

Comment: You didn't happen to have an exception breakpoint did you? That can capture exceptions before they display the message on the console...

Comment: When you got that "crash in main.m", what precisely did it look like? Was the fault highlighted in red or green? What precisely did it say in the editor window where the fault occurred?

Comment: Needless to say, I see the normal behavior in 9.2 (with no exception breakpoints, obviously). I haven't gone back and tested in 9.1 (but can if you absolutely need me to). But I'd be very surprised if this was introduced in 9.1 and returned back to typical behavior in 9.2. I wonder if there's something else going on in your project...

Comment: No, I did not have any exception breakpoints, and it was a non-helpful access violation type message (I don't have it in front of me any more. I don't remember the color any more either.)

Answer (score 0):

Apple didn't remove this feature in Xcode 9+, I have tested both with Xcode 9.1 and Xcode 9.2.

I think there are several ways can reproduce this issue:

1. Using console Filter may cause some logs disappear that moment. Clean filter could bring them back.
2. Using exception breakpoint as Rob says in question comments. Continue execution or disable breakpoint, uncaught exception error would come out.

I suggest you to new a sample project to check it again. If the problem is still there，a screenshot or sample project is welcome.